# Checking if an argument a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, variable-types

I have a JavaScript function that uses `document.getElementById()`. I want to upgrade it to be able to use jQuery selectors (`$(this).parent().find("blah")`), however it needs to be able to use the original method for backwards compatibility. Is there a way I  can test if the argument passed to the function is a string (so I can use `getElementById`) or a jQuery object (not a string).

I could use `.length`, but is this a failsafe method of determining whether the argument is a string?

As long as I can test for strings, the jQuery branch can just go in an `else` - I don't need to make absolutely sure it's not a string, although it would be nice to test if it's jQuery too.

Thanks,

James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Object.prototype.toString.call(your_argument) == "[object String]"
```

Comment: Thanks :-) I tried decyclone's answer and had a bit of trouble. Yours works great though.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, can you comment on how this compares to using typeof?

Comment: @pure_code good explanation http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/08/08/fixing-the-javascript-typeof-operator/

Answer (score 4):

following code returns true:

```
"somestring".constructor == String
```

Comment: +1 Better answer than mine as this works for strings converted to Objects too.

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you're after?

```
var str = "blah";
if (typeof str == "string") {

} else {


}
```

And `length` is definitely not the way to go. Arrays will also have a length property, not to mention any custom object could as well.

Comment: +1 for telling me not to use `.length` - thanks for the advice :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think instanceOf is what you are looking for. See this post: [What is the instanceof operator in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2449254/what-is-the-instanceof-operator-in-javascript/2449264#2449264)

Comment: This will only work for strings converted into an Object, e.g. through `new String("test")`, not primitives.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript has two kinds of strings. This checks for both kinds.

```
function isString (str)
{
  return str instanceof String || typeof str === 'string';
}
```

This will throw always a `ReferenceError`, if the argument is undeclared although `typeof` would not throw an error, because JavaScript evaluates from left to right (see [Short-circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators)).