# __proto__ for IE9 or IE10

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, prototype

Is there any possibility to change the `__proto__` property of an object in IE9 or IE10?
Or is MS still not planning to include it in their JS engine?

I need it in a very special situation where I need to change `__proto__` *after* the object is created.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`__proto__` is going to be standardized in ES6. It is currently in [Appendix B of the ES6 draft](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-object.prototype.__proto__) which in practice means that if it is implemented it needs to have the following semantics.

`__proto__` is both available as an accessor on `Object.prototype` which means that all objects can read and write it by default. However, it can be removed from `Object.prototype` (using `delete`). Once deleted `__proto__` will work as a normal data property with no side effects on setting.

`__proto__` is also a special syntactic form in object literals. It will work to set the [[Prototype]] even if `Object.prototype.__proto__` was deleted.

```
var p = {a: 1};
var o = {
  __proto__: p,
  b: 2
}
```

ES6 also introduces [`Object.setPrototypeOf`](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-object.setprototypeof) (not in the appendix). This is preferred over setting `__proto__`.

`__proto__` is available in all modern browsers, [including Internet Explorer 11](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn342818%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: I hope this is true. Do you know if ES6 will allow to derive efficiently from Array?

Comment: __proto__ is not on a standards track - instead ES6 approved Object.setPrototypeOf for better support https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto

Comment: Yes ES6 will support subclassing built in native classes like Array.

Answer (score 2):

`__proto__` is included in IE11 found in the leaked build of Windows Blue: http://fremycompany.com/BG/2013/Internet-Explorer-11-rsquo-s-leaked-build-395/

Answer (score 1):

A nonanswer as a last case resort:

Change your code so that all the properties that would originally be accessed via the changed prototype are now accessed via explicit delegation over a normal property:

```
{
   a: 17,
   __proto__: { ... }
}
```

to

```
{
   a: 17,
   proto: {...}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly it is you're after since your question didn't specify, but for most uses of proto, you should be able to use `prototype`.

```
var foo = new Bar();
//this also affects foo
Bar.prototype.baz = something;
```

Comment: I didn´t specify, because the only thing I want to know is if IE9/10 supports modifying the __proto__ property, since it´s the only browser that does not support it at the moment.

Comment: I don't understand "new Bar();".  How can you rewrite this using Object.create?

Answer (score 0):

IE 9 and 10 do not support setting the prototype of an object that has already been created, but there is a hack that works in IE 9 and 10:

```
// An alternative to Object.setPrototypeOf() for IE 9 and 10
function addPrototypeTo(obj, prototype) {
    if (!/c/.test(typeof prototype)) {// /c/ matches function and object
        // Throws if prototype is neither an object nor null
        throw new TypeError;
    }
    if (/c|d/.test(typeof obj) && prototype) {// /c|d/ matches function, object, and undefined
        for (var prop, keys = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(prototype), length = keys.length, i = 0; i<length; i++) {
            if (!{}.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop = keys[i])) {// Throws if obj is nullish
                Object.defineProperty(obj, prop, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(prototype, prop));
            }
        }
    }
    return obj;
}
```

The above function is a hack that simply copies all the properties from a prototype object and defines them on another object without overwriting any conflicting property names. Since it uses `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor()` and `Object.defineProperty()`, getters and setters and other property descriptors such as enumerability are maintained.

Now if you wanted to polyfill `Object.setPrototypeOf()` you could simply do this:

```
if (document.documentMode>8) {// IE 9 and above
   Object.setPrototypeOf = Object.setPrototypeOf || addPrototypeTo;
}
```

However this hack obviously does not actually change the prototype of an object. And changes you make to the prototype after calling the function will have no effect on the object. So this may not suit your needs.