# Bypass __proto__ limitation in IE9 and IE10

Tags: javascript, prototype

Hello Javascript ninjas ! I have a pretty tough issue to solve and did not find any satisfying solution.

For a very specific Javascript framework I am developping, I need to be able to set the **__proto__** property of a dynamically created function. I have some kind of generic function factory and need to have common definitions for the created functions.
I'd like not to argue wether or not this is a good practice as I really need to achieve this for perfectly valid reasons.

Here is a small QUnit sample that runs perfectly on Chrome latest version that shows what I need :

```
var oCommonFunctionProto = {};
var fnCreateFunction = function () {
    var fnResult = function () {};
    fnResult.__proto__ = oCommonFunctionProto; // DOES NOT WORK WITH IE9 OR IE10
    return fnResult;
};
var fn1 = fnCreateFunction();
oCommonFunctionProto.randomMethod = function() { return 10; };
equal(fn1.randomMethod(), 10, "__proto__ has been set properly");
var oInstance = new fn1(); // fn1 is instantiable
```

As you can see on this code, anything added to oCommonFunctionProto will be available directly on any function returned by fnCreateFunction method. This allows to build prototype chain on Function objects (like it's often done on prototype chains for objects.

Here is the problem : **__proto__** property is immutable in IE9 and IE10 and sadly, I really need to be compatible with those browsers.
Moreover :

1. I cannot use any third party. I need a fully functional code that do not depend on anything else.
2. As you can see, the **randomMethod** was added after the creation of the function. I really need the prototype chaining as in my scenarios, this objects will me modified after function creations. Simply duplicating oCommonFunctionProto properties on the function prototype will not work.
3. I'm perfectly okay with suboptimal code as long as it does the job. This will be a compatibility hack just for IE9/IE10. AS long as it does the job, I'll be happy.
4. It *could* be okay to set the **__proto__** at function creation. It's better if I can do it afterwards, but if I have no choice, this can be acceptable.

I tried every hack I could but did not find any way to bypass this limitation on IE9/IE10.

TL;DR : I have to be able to set **__proto__** on a javascript function without the help of any third party in IE9 and IE10.

Comment: Several of the questions in the **Related** list look directly apropos. But I don't know enough about this area to tell if they're actual duplicates of your question.

Comment: In particular, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8413505/proto-for-ie9-or-ie10?rq=1

Comment: Already saw that one (and the others actually) but it did not allowed me to do what I need. I'm actually ok with solutions not using __proto__ if it does the job. Thank you for your comment anyway :)

Comment: So you really want `randomMethod` to be a method of the generated constructor function, and not of its instances?  That's what your tests are demonstrating.  If you wanted it on the instances it generates, there are common techniques for that.

Comment: Yeap I need it on the constructor function itself (as well as fields, properties etc...). I need to have a prototype chain on Function objects, not just simple objects.

Comment: Note that [the brains behind es6-shim could not seem to figure out a way of shimming Object.setPrototypeOf, which would be the equivalent of setting __proto__](https://github.com/paulmillr/es6-shim/issues/227). If Paul Miller and the rest of them couldn't figure it out, I doubt I could.

Comment: Wow thanks for the link, very interresting read. However my problem is  -slightly- simpler. I don't need to be able to change __proto__ anywhere any time. Being able to set the __proto__ on a **Function** instance at creation could do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on other answers and discussions, it appears this is just not possible for IE<11.

I finally dropped prototype chains, be it for Objects or Functions, in favor of flattened prototype and notification when a logical "parent" prototype changes to update "child" prototype accordingly.