# Object.getPrototypeOf() confusion

Tags: javascript, dom

How Object.getPrototypeOf(obj) works?

As per definition Object.getPrototypeOf(obj) should return prototype property of an Object or in another way it is same as obj.constructor.prototype.

Objects created with new use the value of the prototype property of their constructor function as their prototype.

Lets take an example:

```
>element = document.getElementById("test")

>a = Object.getPrototypeOf(element)
HTMLDivElement
```

Let's say HTMLDivElement is the prototype of element.

```
>a.constructor.prototype
HTMLDivElement
```

so a.constructor.prototype is HTMLDivElement so Object.getPrototypeOf(a) should return HTMLDivElement but it returns HTMLElement. I am totally confused with definition of getPrototypeOf().

```
>b = Object.getPrototypeOf(a)
```

HTMLElement  ----> why?  a.constructor.prototype is HTMLDivElement

Actually it's returning **proto** property of prototype, isn't it wrong as per definition of getPrototypeOf()?

```
>a.constructor.prototype.__proto__
 HTMLElement
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

quote from https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Inheritance_Revisited

> JavaScript is a bit confusing for developers coming from Java or C++,
>   as it's all dynamic, all runtime, and it has no classes at all. It's
>   all just instances (objects). Even the "classes" we simulate are just
>   a function object.

---

**NOTE that prototype is also AN OBJECT, so it ALSO CAN HAVE IT'S OWN UNIQUE PROTOTYPE**

so code that make you confuse look like this

```
a = Object.getPrototypeOf(element)
b = Object.getPrototypeOf(a)
```

can be translated to this

```
a = element.__proto__
b = element.__ptoto__.__proto__
```

**I think it's now clear that  `a != b`**

---

1) Every **object** in JavaScript **has a prototype**, you can access it through the `__proto__` property

2) **Function** is also an **object** in Javascript

3) Functions also have a `prototype` property

4) We **can** create objects in JavaScript by calling function with keyword `new`

4) Function `prototype` is the **initial** `__proto__` for any objects **created by them**

---

To create new object we can write something like this

```
//here we define a function
function SomeFunctionThatCreateObject() {
    this.someStringProperty = "blablabla";
} 

var obj = new SomeFunctionThatCreateObject(); //we create new object with function

var p = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);
```

this code is equal to this

```
var SomeFunctionThatCreateObject = function(@this) {
    @this.someStringProperty = "blablabla";
    return @this;
};

SomeFunctionThatCreateObject.prototype = {}; //note that prototype is also an object

var obj = {};

obj = SomeFunctionThatCreateObject(obj);

obj.constructor = SomeFunctionThatCreateObject;

obj.__proto__ = SomeFunctionThatCreateObject.prototype;

var p = obj.__proto__;
```

---

PS: also read this 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9220317/474290
and this
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Inheritance_Revisited

Answer (score 0):

```
var elem =  document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0],
a = Object.getPrototypeOf ( elem );
console.log( elem.__proto__ ); //HTMLDivElement
console.log( a ); // HTMLDivElement
console.log( a.__proto__ ); //HTMLElement
console.log( Object.getPrototypeOf ( a ) ); //HTMLElement
```

so `Object.getPrototypeOf` return `object.__proto__` ( `object.constructor.prototype` )

Comment: object.__proto__ and object.constructor.prototype  both are definitely not same .. so i am not getting any part of your logic.