# JavaScript Prototypes: conflicting results

Tags: javascript

Why does,

```
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf({}));
```

logs `{}` to the terminal and

```
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf({}) === Object.prototype);
```

logs `true` to the terminal?

Shouldn't the output on the former be `Object.prototype`?

Comment: Did you out put `console.log(Object.prototype)`? It's the same as `console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf({}))`... that's why the `true`

Comment: `Object.prototype` is a value, more specifically an object, so it prints like an object. It's like when you define your own object property (let's say you have defined `myObj = {id: 1}`). When you print `myObj.id` you wont see `myObj.id`, but 1.

Comment: The `console` API does whatever it wants to do. You should not rely on it being a useful aid when you're doing language semantics research.

Comment: `Object.prototype` is a value, ok. So how do I view methods on the `Object.prototype`? Like `toString()`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Object.getPrototypeOf() confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10013544/object-getprototypeof-confusion)