# What does Object.create( Class.prototype ) do in this code?

Tags: javascript

I'm reading about the [mixin pattern in javascript](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#mixinpatternjavascript) and I encountered this piece of code that I don't understand:

```
SuperHero.prototype = Object.create( Person.prototype );
```

There is actually a typo in the original code (the uppercase H). If I downcase it it works. However, if I actually delete the line everything seems to work the same.

Here is the full code:

```
var Person =  function( firstName , lastName ){
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.lastName =  lastName;
  this.gender = "male";
};

// a new instance of Person can then easily be created as follows:
var clark = new Person( "Clark" , "Kent" );

// Define a subclass constructor for for "Superhero":
var Superhero = function( firstName, lastName , powers ){

    // Invoke the superclass constructor on the new object
    // then use .call() to invoke the constructor as a method of
    // the object to be initialized.

    Person.call( this, firstName, lastName );

    // Finally, store their powers, a new array of traits not found in a normal "Person"
    this.powers = powers;
};

SuperHero.prototype = Object.create( Person.prototype );
var superman = new Superhero( "Clark" ,"Kent" , ["flight","heat-vision"] );
console.log( superman ); 

// Outputs Person attributes as well as powers
```

What does `SuperHero.prototype = Object.create( Person.prototype );` do?

Comment: Realted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2449254/what-is-the-instanceof-operator-in-javascript/2449264#2449264

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It creates a new object that inherits from the `Person` constructor's prototype object.

It would be just like if you did this.

```
SuperHero.prototype = new Person();
```

Except that it creates the `Person` instance without actually invoking the code in the `Person` constructor.

This object is used as the prototype object of the `SuperHero` constructor, so that when you create a `SuperHero` instance, it will inherit all the prototyped properties of `Person`, as well as any prototyped properties added directly to the `SuperHero` prototype object.

Comment: Ahhh, so if there's `Person.prototype.die = function(){...}` I can then do `superhero.die()` ?

Comment: @Duopixel: Exactly. :) The prototype chain will search in the order of `object -> SuperHero.prototype -> Person.prototype -> Object.prototype -> null;`

Comment: @graystateiscoming +1 btw - quick question: "without actually invoking the code in the Person constructor". This part is throwing me off, what do you mean by that?

Comment: @mcpDESIGNS: In ECMAScript 3, you could only create a custom object by invoking a constructor function. So to create a `Person`, you would need to invoke the `Person` function using `new`, as in `var p = new Person()`. But in ECMAScript 5, we get `Object.create`, which lets us create an object that has the exact same prototype chain as an object made using `new`, except that we didn't need to actually call the `Person` function. This is useful if we want a plain `Person` object without the side effects of the constructor function.

Comment: Ah very nice, so it doesn't actually "Run" any of the code/functions inside, it simply lets the prototypes be accessed / inherited / whatever. Is there any specific reason its `Object.create( Person.prototype );` not just `Object.create( Person );` as it would be if we used the old `SuperHero.prototype = new Person();` method

Comment: @mcpDESIGNS: Right. The reason we don't pass a `Person` function as the argument, but instead we pass the prototype object directly is that it opens up the door to create prototype objects that aren't actually part of any constructor function. Say if I have this object `var prot = {foo:"bar"}`, I can can create a bunch of other objects that inherit from this object by doing `Object.create(prot)`. Not a constructor function in sight, yet I still get to use prototypal inheritance.

Comment: Very cool, looks like I'll have to start trying to use this, as soon as I can stop supporting stupid IE7 haha

Comment: @mcpDESIGNS: Use it today! :) http://jsfiddle.net/KAtmJ/ This is a shim that lets you do nearly the same. It doesn't support the second argument to `Object.create`, and doesn't let you use `null` as the prototype object, but it does let you create objects that inherit from a specified prototype. Enjoy! :)

Comment: Thanks! Weirdly I added that to the top of my JS library with and got `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL` error... strange, can't figure out why.

Comment: @mcpDESIGNS: That happens sometimes when you copy/paste from jsfiddle. There's an invisible invalid character that jsfiddle uses for its code formatting. Often it will appear near the end of the code. If you put your cursor at the end of the code (or some characters past the end), and use your left arrow key to slowly move backward through the characters, at some point, you'll notice that the cursor doesn't move for one single keypress. That's where the invisible character is. You just need to delete it by positioning the cursor alongside it, and hitting delete.

Comment: ...or just delete all the code you pasted, and retype it manually. :)

Comment: Yuuup that was it, damn jsfiddle haha

Answer (score 1):

It does exactly as the docs state:

> Creates a new object with the specified prototype object and
>   properties.

The `proto` in this case is `Person`:

The parameter states the following:

> The object which should be the prototype of the newly-created object.

Your code `Object.create( Person.prototype );` returns an object that copies the properties (in this case the firstName, lastName, and gender) of a person and assigns them to a SuperHero.

Note the similarities between a `Person` and a `SuperHero` they both contain a `firstName` and a `lastName`.  Note also the differences, the `Person` contains a `gender` property while your `SuperHero` contains a `powers` property.

Comment: `Object.create` doesn't copy any properties. The object created using `Object.create(Person.prototype)` will not have the `firstName`, `lastName`, and `gender` properties that are assigned in the `Person` constructor.

Comment: But it doesn't really even obtain them... that is unless they are manually copied to the object, which in this case, it is inside the `SuperHero` constructor with `Person.call(this, firstName, lastName);` where the `Person` function will directly assign them. But it's not coming from the `Object.create(Person.prototype)`, because those properties are not prototyped.

Comment: @graystateiscoming they inherit those properties.

Comment: Nope, the properties are not inherited. They are assigned directly to the object because of the `Person.call(this...)` invocation.

Answer (score 1):

```
SuperHero.prototype = Object.create( Person.prototype );
```

This is basically letting `SuperHero` inherit all of the properties/prototypes of `Person`.  It is almost the same as using `new`, but in the new ECMAScript 5 *Object.create()` way.  This could also be written like so, if it helps understand it any more.

```
SuperHero.prototype = new Person();
```

I don't like linking the prototypes specifically, because it means the two prototypes are intertwined, and I prefer to have one be the SubClass, one the SuperClass.

A good way to see them yourself is do something like this. Here you can really see the inheritance that `SuperHero` is getting from `Person`. Notice it has all of the properties (first/last/etc), and it's additional Powers.

[**jsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/DccsD/)

```
var person = new Person();
SuperHero.prototype = person; // inheritance here
// the Object.create way is ECMAScript 5 (which not all browsers support yet sadly)

var superman = new SuperHero( "Clark" ,"Kent" , ["flight","heat-vision"] );
console.log( person );
console.log( superman ); ​
```