# Understanding instanceof with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, instanceof

I have a basic understanding of instanceof in JavaScript, testing if the left hand side object "is of" the right hand side object type.  The following 2 examples help me understand that...

```
var demo1 = function() {};
demo1.prototype = {
foo: "hello"
};

var demo2 = function() {
var pub = {
    bar:"world"
};
return this.pub;
};

var obj1 = new demo1();
var obj2 = new demo2();

console.log(obj1 instanceof demo1);  //returns true
console.log(obj2 instanceof demo2);  //returns true
```

But on this 3rd example, I get false and I don't understand why....

```
var o = {}; // new Object;
o.toString(); // [object Object]
console.log(o instanceof toString); //returns false
```

Thanks for any help in understanding whats going on.  Also...is is possible to make the 3rd example true?

Thanks again

Comment: Your `demo2` function is screwed up. There is no `this.pub`, so it will return `undefined`, and when called with the `new` operator this will result in an empty object (beeing an `instanceof demo2` at least)

Comment: It returns true for me, I'm using an example based off of T.J. Crawford's blog here - http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/03/anonymouses-anonymous.html

Comment: Yes, `obj2 instanceof demo2` is `true` for me, too. Still, your constructor is useless and could be replaced by an empty function. I can't see how yours came from any example in that very good article.

Comment: Bergi I didn't post example 2 as a best practice for patterns, I know that.  It's based on a response from a blog comment on that article.  That's all.  I plan on using standard patterns to achieve my goals.  Thanks for the heavy critique on staying away from the style mentioned above.  And yes its a great article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`o` is an `object`; `toString` is a `function`.  They are different types in JavaScript.

```
alert(typeof(o));  //"object"
alert(typeof(toString)); //"function"
```

JavaScript makes a distinction between objects and functions.  Therefore, that's why you get `false` returned in your example.

Comment: obj2 is a object and demo2() is a function.  I just tested it within my web console, and yet I get a "return true" with them.  So there has to be more than what you are saying...

Comment: Check out this SO question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2449254/what-is-the-instanceof-operator-in-javascript .  In the accepted answer, a variable on the LHS returns `true` if the object inherit's from the RHS's prototype.  That's what you're doing in your `obj2 = new demo2()` statement.  So `obj2` inherits from `demo2` prototype.  Therefore, `obj2` is an instance of `demo2`.  `o` and `toString` aren't related by a common prototype, so the `instanceof` check returns `false`.  I hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

`toString` does not cause a type change of `o`. It just returns a string representation of the object, without altering it. So, `o` is still a simple object and no `instanceof String`.

```
var o = {}; // new Object object
var ostring = o.toString(); // "[object Object]"
typeof o; // object
typeof ostring; // string - this is a primitive value, not an object; so that
ostring instanceof String; // is false
var stringobj = new String(ostring); // new String object
typeof stringobj; // object
stringobj instanceof String; // true!
o instanceof Object; // also true!
```

See also [MDN reference for the `String` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Distinction_between_string_primitives_and_String_objects).

Answer (score 1):

With an object literal like

```
var o = {}; // new Object;
```

you create an object whose prototype is `Object`. Testing with `instanceof` will not yield any useful information. The only comparison that will yield true is

```
o instanceof Object
```

Comment: Thank you Ingo!  That helps me to understand what I'm comparing things too now!