# How to check the instanceof an instance of an object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, instanceof

I'm working on a JavaScript and I got stuck with some verification :

I'd like to check that the variable given as a parameter was an instance of an instance of an object. To be more clear, here's an example :

```
var Example = function () {
    console.log ('Meta constructor');
    return function () {
        console.log ('Instance of the instance !');
    };
};

var inst = new Example();
assertTrue(inst instanceof Example.constructor); // ok

var subInst = new inst();
assertTrue(subInst instanceof Example.constructor); // FAIL
assertTrue(subinst instanceof inst.constructor); // FAIL
```

How can I check that `subInst` is an instance of `Example.{new}` ? or `inst.constructor` ?

Comment: Check this out

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2449254/what-is-the-instanceof-operator-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
subInst.__proto__ == inst.prototype
```

Comment: Apparently, it's not good to use inst.constructor, how could I check the origin of inst in that case ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you don't check against `.constructor`, you check against the constructing function, that is `Example`. Whenever you're testing the `.constructor` property, this will be the one found on the instance (if you set it on the prototype of the constructor).

So

```
(new Example) instanceof Example; // true
```

Secondly, if your `Example` function is returning a function, then `Example` isn't actually a constructor, and hence you can not do any kind of prototypical inheritance checks on it. A constructor will always return an object, and that object will be an instance of the constructor.

What you have is instead a factory function that creates functions that *might* be used as a constructor. A function will only pass `instanceof` checks for `Function` and `Object`.

```
var Ctor = example(); // PascalCase constructor, camelCase factory
var inst = new Ctor();
inst instanceof Ctor; // true
```

But do take a look at the link posted by @franky, it should give you some insights into what you need to do.

Comment: `(new Example) instanceof Example;` I got false with Chrome :/

Comment: @CyrilN. That is because /your/ `Example` function isn't a constructor, it's a factory function.

Comment: Ok, interesting! :) I need to to have a behavior like the one I used in my question. Is it the best way to do it or is there a better way?

Comment: Your code really doesn't make sense - using the `new` operator with a factory function has no effect.