# javascript prototype object

Tags: javascript

1.

```
function MyConstructor() {}
var myobject = new MyConstructor();
MyConstructor.prototype = {protest:"maizere"};

[ myobject instanceof MyConstructor,     // false !
myobject.constructor == MyConstructor, // true !
myobject instanceof Object ]           // true
console.log(myobject.protest)          //undefined
```

This proves that myobject does not inherit properties and method from MyConstructor prototype anymore.

But see next code below:

2.

```
function MyConstructor() {}
var myobject = new MyConstructor();
MyConstructor.prototype.protest= "Maizere";//Do this line gets hoisted?or something else

[ myobject instanceof MyConstructor,     // true!
myobject.constructor == MyConstructor, // true !
myobject instanceof Object ]           // true
console.log(myobject.protest)          //Maizere
```

Why is this happening?what is the exact definition of internal prototype?This also  proves even after the instantiation of the object , **proto** is  refering to MyConstructor prototype.If so than why the first(1.) code not referring to MyConstructor prototype?
since the property is being added after the instantiation of an object in the second code and the internal prototype of the object receives it ,this means we can change the prototype properties later and still see the effect in the instance .But same definition is not working when prototype properties is replaced in the first code?

Comment: Read: [`.prototype`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/572897/139010) and [`instanceof`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2449254/139010)

Comment: Using `new` sets up a relationship between the new object, and the *current* `.prototype` of the constructor. That relationship does not change if you give the `.prototype` of the constructor a new object.

Answer (score 1):

I might be wrong with this but it looks like when you do:

```
MyConstructor.prototype = {protest:"maizere"};
```

You're overriding your prototype with an anonymous object definition, thus when you just add a new property like:

```
MyConstructor.prototype.protest= {"Maizere"};
```

Your class keeps its prototype and it works like a charm.

Comment: `MyConstructor.prototype.protest= {"Maizere"};` is not valid syntax, so I assume you mean `MyConstructor.prototype.protest= "Maizere";`

Answer (score 0):

`MyConstructor.prototype =` overwrites the entire `prototype` object.

> The `instanceof` operator tests whether an object has in its prototype chain the prototype property of a constructor

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/xtqhp/

```
function MyConstructor () {}
MyConstructor.prototype = {'xyz': 'zyx'};
//true
console.log((new MyConstructor) instanceof MyConstructor);

function MyConstructor2 () {}
var mc2 = new MyConstructor2;
MyConstructor2.prototype = {'xyz': 'zyx'};
//false
console.log(mc2 instanceof MyConstructor2);
```

By the way, `MyConstructor.prototype.protest = {"Maizere"};` is not valid syntax.

Comment: even if the Prototype object is completely replaced  as per the second code either it still have reference to MyConstructor prototype which is now a normal object or this line MyConstructor.prototype.protest = "Maizere"; gets hoisted

Comment: since the property is being added after the instantiation of an object ,the internal prototype  of the object receives it ,this means we can change the prototype properties later and still see the effect in the instance .But same definition is not working when prototype properties is replaced?

Answer (score 0):

So, this is one of the reasons I have this article bookmarked:

[Constructors Considered Mildly Confusing](http://joost.zeekat.nl/constructors-considered-mildly-confusing.html)

Basically, what's happening in the first block of code is that you're overwriting MyConstructor's prototype object with a new object.  Whereas, in the second block, you're adding a property to the existing prototype object.

Comment: Does the newly added properties gets hoisted ?

Comment: since we are adding the properties after the instantiation of the object.