# confusion with instanceof Array and String

Tags: javascript

i read [instanceof answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2449254/what-is-the-instanceof-operator-in-javascript),but i have a question
When i code

```
["a","b"] instanceof Array
```

why it reutrns true as the same as

```
new Array("a","b") instanceof Array
```

while

```
"a" instanceof String
```

returns false not as the same as

```
new String("ab") instanceof String
```

? 
very appreciate for your answers and help!

Comment: so you're asking what instance is "a"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `instanceof` check is [defined as](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.8.6):

> When the [[HasInstance]] internal method of F is called with value V,
>   the following steps are taken:
>
> 1. If V is not an object, return false.
> 2. Let O be the result of calling the [[Get]] internal method of F with property name "prototype".
> 3. If Type(O) is not Object, throw a TypeError exception.
> 4. Repeat
>
>    1. Let V be the value of the [[Prototype]] internal property of V.
>    2. If V is null, return false.
>    3. If O and V refer to the same object, return true.

So string fails the very first step because string is not an object. Also note that `new String` doesn't return a string but an object constructed from a constructor called `String`. This is one example how Java and Javascript is completely different.

Here is also code for a custom `instanceOf`, make it work however you like then:

```
function instanceOf(F, V) {
    if( typeof F !== "function" ) {
        throw new Error( "F must be a constructor" );
    }
    if( Object(V) !== V ) {
        return false; //not an object
    }
    var O = F.prototype;
    if( Object(O) !== O ) {
        throw new Error( ".prototype must be an object" );
    }
    while( true ) {
        V = Object.getPrototypeOf(V);
        if( V == null ) {
            return false;
        }
        if( V === O ) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks,i understand the first item,but what is O and [[Get]] internal method?Are they javascript internal implements?the custom instanceof(F,V),F parameter represent what?how to use this program?

Comment: @user2245634 they are technical explanations how something should work. To use [[Get]] Operation of `F` with property name `"prototype"`, you just do `F.prototype`. `[[Get]]` Operation is also explained separately in the specification.

Answer (score 2):

For strings, you have both

- primitive strings (the ones you manipulate most of the times, and that you get from literals)
- and instances of the `String` class.

And they're not the same.

Here's [what the MDN says on the distinction between both](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Distinction_between_string_primitives_and_String_objects).

Another way to see the difference, which the MDN doesn't point, is that you can add properties on objects :

```
var a = "a";
a.b = 3; // doesn't add the property to a but to a wrapped copy
console.log(a.b);  // logs undefined
a = new String("a");
a.b = 3;
console.log(a.b);  // logs 3
```

(remember that most of the times, you should use primitive strings)

For arrays, you only have arrays, there is nothing like a primitive array.

Comment: +1 for the remark about properties of objects vs properties of primitive strings!

Answer (score 0):

In your case

```
"a"
```

is not a String Object, it is a String literal or as it is called a "primitive".
So JS is not betraying you, claiming, that "a" is not an instance of String.
CF [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) on `String`

Comment: A string literal and a string primitive are not the same. A literal is a *syntactic* construct. It tells the lexer that the sequence of characters is supposed to be a string. A string primitive is data type which exists at *run time* (not parsing time). It's true though that a string *literal* always results in a string *primitive*.

Comment: Thanks for making that clear. In Javascript I thought it would could be used interchangeably.

Comment: It probably is often used interchangeably, but that doesn't mean it's correct. Plus I'm a bit picky ;)