# Specific typeof array, and possible benefits & browser support

Tags: javascript

I was experimenting with `Uint16Array()` (which is something new to me in js) and I created an array of 5 numbers like so:

```
var test = new Uint16Array(5);
```

then assigned a number to each cell.

then when I tried in my console `typeof` test returned `"object"` although when I did `alert(test)` the message-box returned `[object Uint16Array]`.My question is how can I check the exact type of the variable / array "test" like alert returned?

Correct me if I'm mistaken but wouldn't this be more efficient, to use specific variable types for your data and furthermore is it supported from major browsers?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the name of an object's type in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332422/how-do-i-get-the-name-of-an-objects-type-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to specifically check whether a variable is of the type Uint16Array, you can use instanceof:

```
var test = new Uint16Array(5);
console.log(test instanceof Uint16Array)
```

will result in `true`:

For more on instanceof see [What is the instanceof operator in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2449254/what-is-the-instanceof-operator-in-javascript)

Comment: Hm I agree this seems the most proper way of checking the variable.

Answer (score 1):

Array is actually an object so

```
typeof [1,2,3]
```

will return `"object"`.

Now when you do alert(array) you're actually calling `Object.prototype.toString()` method which formats resulting string. In this case `[object Uint16Array]`.

Typeof returns object because it is an object. Despite the fact you initialized **Uint16Array** - it is still an object :). Like for example:

```
function car() {}
var c = new car();
typeof c === 'object' // => true
```

Numbers, strings, objects etc. are generic data types. Look [here for js datatypes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/7wkd9z69%28v=vs.94%29.aspx).

An **ugly** method to check for exact type would be this:

```
array.toString().split(/\b/g)[3]
```

Why index 3 ? because returned string is [object type]; so the parts are like this:

- 0 - [
- 1 - object
- 3 - space
- 4 - type
- 5 - ]

Comment: yes I know it is still an object, so I suppose we could check for the exact type of the array by comparing the arrayName.toString() result?

Comment: No, his alert is not using `Array.prototype.toString` - that would not have returned `[object Uint16Array]`. Not all objects have `toString`-methods that yield such strings - most prominently, plain `Array`s don't.

Answer (score 1):

You can test more precisely for type in Javascript using the triple equality operator (`===`) so that something like `typeof(function() { }) === 'function'` will return true. However, Uint16Array is a constructor that creates an Array object, therefore any derivative of that will be an object, as well.

As far as making it more efficient in browsers, you can count this kind of optimization as "trying too hard" because it's not going to save you much (if any) noticeable amount of speed or efficiency. There are, of course, caveats to this where your data is Large, but generally you won't see an improvement by programming towards type in Javascript. That's not to say it's worthless, just that it generally isn't going to be something worthwhile most of the time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes I know in general it is "trying to hard" but I was thinking a use case in large amount of data and memory limit in mobile applications.

Comment: In that case it would likely be far more efficient to just write a native app that does the processing, or simply outsource the processing to a server built specifically to process data. Javascript is a pretty fast language already, but if resources in my budget were tight, I'd skip it and write a native app for a mobile device instead. That being said, if you absolutely are limited to local Javascript on mobile ONLY, then unless you're doing something like intense prime calculations or something, don't worry about it. I have no numbers to back this up, only experience...

Comment: ... So if you do some research and come up with some hard numbers, I'd love to be proven wrong, just to get a look at those numbers. :)

Answer (score 1):

> how can I check the exact type of the variable / array "test" like alert returned?

Use [`Object.prototype.toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) to get the internal [[Class]] value of an object. Your alert seems to have used this method because `Uint16Array.prototype` does not overwrite it, as opposed to e.g. `Array.prototype`. Some examples:

```
Object.prototype.toString.call( {} ); // [object Object]
Object.prototype.toString.call( [] ); // [object Array]
Object.prototype.toString.call( new Uint16Array(5) ); // [object Uint16Array]
```