# what is by mean an instance? or instance of?

Tags: javascript

I am struggling with the keyword 'instance'. In Java, I only know how to create the "new" keyword. Now, I'm learning about JavaScript, some author heavily used the word 'instance':

```
function Foo(){}

var foo = new Foo();

//foo is now an instance of Foo
console.log(foo instanceof Foo ) //=> true
```

What is the purpose of making `foo instanceof Foo`?

Comment: Please dont mix Javascript and Java. They are vastly different. You want Javascript

Comment: Read about "OOP inheritance" in general, and "prototypes" in JavaScript, you'll get the idea. You just need a bit more research...

Comment: what is the purpose of making foo instanceof Foo?

Comment: @user3057928, the command (foo instanceof Foo) is a type-checker that returns true or false. It's there so you can determine if foo *is* an instance of the class Foo. If it isn't an instance of that class, it will return "false". For instance, `var notFoo = 1; notFoo instanceof Foo;` will return false, since notFoo is not an instance of Foo.

Comment: Maybe the following will help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941 An instance is an object that could have been created by a constructor function (this case Foo) Foo has a prototype and all members that cannot be found on the instances will be looked up on Foo's prototype so prototype declared members are shared.

Comment: @user3057928 if your concept about instance and instance of is cleared by my answer you can upvote and select my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instanceof is a binary operator,
The instanceof allows to check if the object is created by given constructor:

The instanceof operator returns true if object is an instance of class. It returns true if true if class is present in the object's prototype chain. It returns false if object is not an instance of class, or if object is null.

```
function Rabbit() { }
var rabbit = new Rabbit

alert(rabbit instanceof Rabbit) // true
```

In the example above, the match is found at the first step, because: rabbit.**proto** == Rabbit.prototype.

Few helpful links

[What is the instanceof operator in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2449254/what-is-the-instanceof-operator-in-javascript)

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp

http://javascript.info/tutorial/instanceof#the-instanceof-operator

Answer (score 1):

> The instanceof operator compares an object to a specified type. You
> can use it to test if an object is an instance of a class, an instance
> of a subclass, or an instance of a class that implements a particular
> interface.

For more [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html).

But this is in `Java`. Not `Javascript`

Answer (score 1):

You have a class `Person`. By a class I mean you define what are the **attributes** that a **`Person`** should have **eg:name,age,weight etc.**. Now you can say,  I am creating an **"instanceof"** Person with name "Peter" , age =25 and weight ="70 pounds".  Now. when you call **"is instanceof"** the  properties of the object which you have are mapped against the the attributes/signature/metadata of the class to which you are comparing..

Eg:

```
class Person
{
    String name;
    int age;
    double weight;
}

....

Person p = new Person();
boolean b = (p isInstanceOf Person) // returns true
```

Answer (score 0):

**instanceof**

JavaScript doesn't have classes (yet), but it does have constructor functions, an instanceof operator that defines a relationship between objects and constructors, and a form of inheritance based on prototype chains.

**instance**

A variable will hold a reference to an instance of an object.

The actual object is an instance.

Answer (score 0):

`instanceof` is a **keyword**.

It checks if an object reference is an instance of a type, and returns a boolean value;

The `<object-reference> instanceof Object` will return **true** for all non-null object references, since all Java objects are inherited from Object. `instanceof` will always return false if `<object-reference>` is **null.**

or simply we can say that:

The **instanceof** operator provides us with a way to test which constructor function was used to create a given object.It evaluates as true if the constructor function of the specific object referenced was the one used to create the object being tested and evaluates as false if the constructor function of the specified object was not the one used.