# What is purpose of the javascript constructor prologue?

Tags: javascript, node.js, design-patterns, constructor

I often come across the following constructor prologue in many node.js/javascript sources.

```
function MyClass () {
    // prologue
    if (!(this instanceof MyClass)) {
        return new MyClass();
    }
    // do actual constructor logic
}
```

Could you please explain what is this for? Thanks.

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/a/2449264/3556874

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`instanceof` checks an object to see if it was likely to have been constructed via the given constructor function. That prologue is there to handle the case where someone calls the `MyClass` constructor function without using `new`. It means you can use `MyClass` the way it's meant to be used:

```
var c = new MyClass();
```

...or without `new`:

```
var c = MyClass();
```

In the latter case, within the call to `MyClass`, `this` won't be `instanceof MyClass` (it'll either be `undefined` [in strict mode] or the global object [in loose mode]), and so the author knows that the caller didn't use `new`, and just has the function do the `new` for them by doing `return new MyClass();` instead of its normal construction work.

Some people like to do that so the `new` is optional, others think it's a bad idea to make the `new` optional like that. In the bad old days before strict mode, the alternative was to detect the caller's failure to use `new` and throw an exception:

```
// Old pre-strict code
if (!(this instanceof MyClass)) {
    throw "MyClass is a constructor, use new";
}
```

If you don't do that, and you're using loose mode, and you assign properties to `this`, you'll be assigning properties to the global object (which are global variables), which is a Bad Idea<sup>(tm)</sup>.

But now we have strict mode, and this is one of the many reasons to use it:

```
"use strict"; // At the top of the file or `script` block

function MyClass() {
    // No need for the check anymore
    this.someProperty = someValue;
}
```

That code is entirely safe from the issue of accidentally creating global variables, because the `this.someProperty = someValue;` line will throw if someone calls `MyClass` without `new` (because `this` will be `undefined`). (And it doesn't matter whether the *caller* uses strict mode; it's sufficient that we use strict mode in the code defining the `MyClass` constructor.)

Some will still prefer to make `new` optional, of course, in which case they still need the prologue.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid direct calling a contructor to register some variables to global, this is a famous flaw of JavaScript.

```
function Foo() {
    // don't do prologue
    this.foo = 'foo';
}

Foo(); // direct call a constructor

console.log(window.foo) // foo, global is polluted.
```

Comment: The fault, dear Brutus, is not in our stars / But in ourselves...

Comment: comment.replace('rutus', 'rendan');
Jus joking, I'm fan of stars.