# Handle JSON data in a LIST using JQuery

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, json, jersey

I am using Ajax&Jquery to handle the JSON data( In List) comes from the server, however, the client end cannot accept the JSON data and constantly popped up the error method.

I have implemented a renderList() method to parse the List ,however it still doesn't work.

The following is my Javascript and Java code.

Can someone help me out ? Thanks in advance.

**JavaScript:**

```
var serviceURL = "http://localhost:8080/TransportationNetwork/rest/paths";


$('#findPaths').click(function() {
        getPaths();
});

function getPaths() {
    console.log('display paths');
    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url: serviceURL,
        dataType:'json', // data type get back from server
        data:'st=' + dataToServer(), //data sent to server 
        success: renderList,
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert('Path Finder: ' + textStatus);
        }
    });
}



function dataToServer() {
    var array = "";
        str1 = $('#source').val();
        str2 = $('#target').val();

    array = str1 + "," + str2;

    return array;
}

function renderList(data) {
    var list = data == null ? [] : (data instanceof Array ? data : [data]);

$('#PathList li').remove();
$.each(list, function(index, path) {
    $('#PathList').append('<li>'+ path.source + ' -> ' + path.target + ': ' + path.weight + '</li>');
});
```

}

**Java:**
In Resource File:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<DirectedEdge> pathsInfo(@QueryParam("st") String st) {
    System.out.println("Searching paths : " + st);
    return pathDao.getEdgeList(st);
}
```

***The returned DirectedEdge Objects:***

```
public class DirectedEdge {
private int source;
private int target;
private double weight;

public DirectedEdge() {

}

public DirectedEdge(int v, int w, double weight) {
    super();
    this.source = v;
    this.target = w;
    this.weight = weight;
}
.... Other code  ...
}
```

[Testing Result from Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwpUZ.png)

Comment: are you sure you're sending the data in the right format?

Comment: as you can see the picture from the bottom "testing result from server". i was using postman to do the test the data comes from the server is indeed in json format.  @devlincarnate

Comment: I understand the data coming from the server is json. My question is whether you've verified the data you're sending TO the server is in the correct format.  You haven't specified a contentType so I'm assuming the server is expecting you to send the default contentType.  What is the value of `'st=' + dataToServer()` ?

Comment: Oh, I do not need to sent JSON data to Server, but I need the JSON data sent from the Server to Client side, the "st" is a java variable (as can be seen from the java code) , it is used to accept two points id, and I use a "," to separate them, it is in String data type.  @devlincarnate

Comment: I have posted the specific question in this page, please check it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33572801/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-when-receiving-json-data-from-server  @devlincarnate

Answer (score 0):

your json should return as a `string`, not an `Array`. try using `JSON.parse`

[JSON.parse docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

`renderList` should look something like this:

```
function renderList(data) {
  var parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
  var list = parsedData == null ? [] : (parsedData instanceof Array ? parsedData : [parsedData]);
}
```

FYI: `instanceof` is rather unreliable. I recommend adding this helper method to your code for determining types in the future:

```
function getType(data) {
  return Object.prototype.toString.call(data).slice(8, -1);
}
```

This will return a string representation of the object type.

You can see more on this topic here:
[instanceof in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2449254/what-is-the-instanceof-operator-in-javascript)

Comment: I tried your code, but it still gives me that alert method. @john

Comment: @user3765602 well what's the status and what's the message?

Comment: try setting the `dataType` property of `$.ajax` to "json".  @user3765602

Comment: the dataType is json originally, i do not need to change it. but it does work. @john

Comment: it just popped up the alert message "Path Finder:  error"  @peeskillet

Comment: Can you debug the error. Determine what status code is returned from your server. It is impossible to determine the issue otherwise @user3765602

Comment: Hi the testing result from the server using POSTMAN is shown at the end of the context, can you check it please? @JohnStrong

Comment: looks good. What is the value returned for `errorThrown` in your error function? @user3765602

Comment: log the result using `console.log` and debug as opposed to printing it in an alert message. Let me know what the value is (it should be an object containing information about the failed request) @user3765602