# Best way to know if something is a Map type

Tags: javascript, comparison

I think this might be a little tricky, or it might have been answered already, but I can't find it.

Anyways, I want to know if the variable that was passed in to my function is a `Map()`

OFC, the `typeof` operator would return object for a map.

I was wondering if I should be doing something like the following, would it make sense?

```js
var something = new Map()

console.log(something.constructor.prototype.toString())
console.log(Map.prototype.toString())
console.log(something.constructor.prototype.toString() === Map.prototype.toString())

console.log(something.constructor.toString())
console.log(Map.toString())
console.log(something.constructor.toString() === Map.toString())
```

This means that there are 2 "hacky" ways to know which is the type, but I know this is not correct.

Can anyone come up with a better solution than comparing prototypes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the instanceof operator in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2449254/what-is-the-instanceof-operator-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little time I just reminded the `instanceof` operator

The correct way would be to use that operator, as you know for sure that it won't lead to any error when comparing it when the variable doesn't have a constructor. Like when the variable is `undefined` or `null`

This would be correct

```js
var something = new Map()
var nothing = null

console.log(something instanceof Map)
console.log(something instanceof Object)
console.log(nothing instanceof Map)
```

As pointed out int he comments, because of the way the `instaceof` operator works, it might be that if there is a variable that inherits from `Map` the `instanceof` validation would still be passing

As you can see, `something instanceof Object` is true, which happens because the `Map` inherits from `Object`

You can see more information about this behaviour in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2449254/what-is-the-instanceof-operator-in-javascript) and you could use the following comparator

`something.construtor === Map`

But it would have the same caveats that we were trying to avoid by using the `instanceof` operator

Comment: A *very* edge case would be if something inherited from `Map.prototype` which you did not want to pass the test - in which case, use `something.constructor === Map` instead