# How instanceof works?

Tags: javascript, prototype

Given this code:

```
/**
 * Transform base class
 */
function Transform() {
    this.type = "2d";
}

Transform.prototype.toString = function() {
    return "Transform";
}

/**
 * Translation class.
 */
function Translation(x, y) {
    // Parent constructor
    Transform.call(this);

    // Public properties
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

// Inheritance
Translation.prototype = Object.create(Transform.prototype);

translation = new Translation(10, 15);

console.log(translation instanceof Transform); // true
console.log(translation instanceof Translation); // true

console.log(translation.__proto__); // Transform
console.log(translation.constructor); // Transform
```

Why `translation.constructor` is `Transform` and not `Translation`?
Also, which property allows `instanceof` to know that `translation` is an instance of 
`Translation` (if it's not `__proto__` nor `constructor`)?

Comment: It looks at the prototype chain, as you could have discovered with a quick check of [the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof)

Comment: `Translation` is also a `Transform`.

Comment: After setting `Translation.prototype`, you need to set `Translation.prototype.constructor = Translation` [Classical inheritance with Object.create()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create#Classical_inheritance_with_Object.create())

Comment: @adiga then why `instanceof` still works?

Comment: Because that's how `instanceof` works. It will check if the provided constructor appears **anywhere** in the prototype chain. This is why `translation instanceof Object` also returns `true`. As `Object.getPrototypeOf(Transform.prototype) === Object.prototype`

Comment: That's my problem, I don't see it appearing anywhere. Would you consider reopening since none of the linked answers are useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why `translation.constructor` is `Transform` and not `Translation`?

Because you have missed a step while creating a subclass `Translation`. Every function gets a default `prototype` property and this has a `constructor` property equal to the function itself.

```js
function Translation() {
}

const translation = new Translation();

console.log(Translation.prototype.constructor === Translation)
console.log(translation.constructor === Translation)

console.log(translation.__proto__ === Translation.prototype)
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(translation) === Translation.prototype)
```

So, why doesn't `translation.constructor` return `Translation` in your case? Because, to inherit from `Transform`, the default `prototype` is overwritten.

```
Translation.prototype = Object.create(Transform.prototype);
```

^ When you did that, the default `prototype` object which had the `constructor` got overwritten with a new object. If you check the documentation for [Classical inheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create#Classical_inheritance_with_Object.create()), you have missed a step in creating this inheritance. You need to set the `constructor` property to the original function. This will help identify the constructor function that created an object

```
Translation.prototype.constructor = Translation
```

If you don't add this, a call to `translation.constructor` will be as follows:

- It will look for a `constructor` property directly on the object. It doesn't exist.
- Then it will look inside `Translation.prototype`. This object was overwritten by the `Object.create(Transform.prototype)` line and the object doesn't have any *own* properties.
- `Translation.prototype` falls back to `Transform.prototype`. There is a `constructor` property here an it is the function `Transform`. This is why you get `Transform`

And as to why `instanceof` works is explained in [this answer from the duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6537620/3082296).