# how do I know if my variable has 'any' data type?

Tags: typescript

I can check if my variable is a string by using the code below

```
if (typeof myVariable === "string") {

}
```

but now I need to check if my variable is `any` or not. I try using the code below

```
if (typeof myVariable === "any") {

}
```

but I have error

[image]

> This condition will always return 'false' since the types '"string" |
> "number" | "bigint" | "boolean" | "symbol" | "undefined" | "object" |
> "function"' and '"any"' have no overlap.ts(2367) Invalid typeof
> comparison value.

so how to solve this?

Comment: You do know `typeof` is both a runtime JavaScript *and* compile-time TypeScript operator, right (currently, your usage is mixing both)? And that there is no `any` data type in JavaScript? And that `any` is not so much a type, but more of a type-checker off-switch, telling the compiler "anything goes here"?