# How to print a nest list of map with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a function which converts a set of Javascript objects into a map. However, I get an object which cannot be navigated for its values; Here is the sample json

```json
{
   "products":{
      "lemonade":{
         "product-type":"beverage",
         "product-details":{
            "calories":"129",
            "product-categories":[
               222,
               444
            ]
         }
      },
      "limeade":{
         "product-type":"beverage",
         "product-details":{
            "calories":"220",
            "product-categories":[
               222,
               444
            ],
            "salesIndex":{
               "percentage":1101,
               "demographics":"region-1"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Here is my function to convert to a map:

```js
function objectToMap(o) {
  const m = new Map();
  console.log(`Processing for fragment ${fragment}`);
  for (const k of Object.keys(o)) {
    if (o[k] instanceof Object) {
      console.log(`Key is ${k} and object is ${JSON.stringify(o[k])}`);
      m.set(k, objectToMap(o[k]));
    } else {
      console.log(`Not an object ::Key is ${k} and object is
           ${JSON.stringify(o[k])}`);
      m.set(k, o[k]);
    }
  }
  return m;
}
```

Here is how I try to use and print the map:

```js
const m1 = objectToMap(obj.products);
printMap(m1);

function printMap(map) {
  for (const k of map.keys()) {
    console.log(`Current key is ${k} and value is
${map.get(k)}`);
    if (map.get(k) instanceof Map) {
      printMap(map.get(k));
    } else {
      console.log(`No it is not a map :: Key is ${k} and value is ${map.get(k)}`);
    }
  }
}
```

However, I get for some this key, salesIndex, [object Map],  why are the key, values not printed?

Comment: What is `fragment`? And what would be the desired output for your example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why are the key, values not printed?

They *are* printed, but the primitive values only get printed (later) when the object is passed to the recursive call, and there the `else` block is executed, i.e. when you arrive at the base case of the recursion.

Your code is fine, but you should avoid printing the *value* when you're not yet at that base case, as that value still needs to be passed to the recursive call, which will take care of printing the deeper key/values.

I would suggest:

- To only print the key (not the value) when the value is still an *object*
- Print with indentation so it is much clearer what the structure is of the data
- In `objectToMap`, support `null` values: for that you need to change the is-object test.

That's the most important, but I'd also:

- In `objectToMap`, use `Object.entries` instead of `Object.keys` so you get both the key and the value as your loop variables
- Similarly, in `printMap`, use `map.entries` instead of `map.values` so you get both the key and the value as your loop variables
- In `objectToMap`, as you call `map.set()` in both `if` and `else` cases, start with the call, and differentiate the argument with a conditional (ternary) operator

So like this:

```js
// For the purpose of this answer, console.log removed from this function:
function objectToMap(o) {
  const m = new Map();
  for (const [k, v] of Object.entries(o)) { // Get both key and value
    // Use conditional operator and better way to check for objects:
    m.set(k, Object(v) === v ? objectToMap(v) : v);
  }
  return m;
}

// Extra argument for printing with indentation
function printMap(map, tab="") { 
  for (const [k, v] of map.entries()) {
    // Don't print here yet...
    if (v instanceof Map) {
      console.log(`${tab}${k}:`); // Only print the key here...
      printMap(v, tab + "    "); // ...as recursion will take care of the value(s)
    } else {
      console.log(`${tab}${k} = ${v}`);
    }
  }
}

// demo
const obj = {"products":{"lemonade":{"product-type":"beverage","product-details":{"calories":"129","product-categories":[222,444]}},"limeade":{"product-type":"beverage","product-details":{"calories":"220","product-categories":[222,444],"salesIndex":{"percentage":1101,"demographics":"region-1"}}}}};

const m = objectToMap(obj.products);
printMap(m);
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer to your question is that you get the `[object Map]` string whenever you try to interpolate a `Map` type into a `String` type. So say

```js
const myMap = new Map([['key', 'value']])

// calling toString implicitly
console.log('implicitly ->', `${myMap}`)

// calling toString explicitly
console.log('explicitly ->', myMap.toString())
```

Similarly you get `[object Object]` for objects

```js
const myObj = { key: 'value' };

// calling toString implicitly
console.log('implicitly ->', `${myObj}`)

// calling toString explicitly
console.log('explicitly ->', myObj.toString())
```

Array types `toString` method is a join so essentially `myArray.join(',') === myArray.toString()`.

```js
const myArr = [1, 2, 3];

// calling toString implicitly
console.log('implicitly ->', `${myArr}`)

// calling toString explicitly
console.log('explicitly ->', myArr.toString())

// calling toString explicitly
console.log('join ->', myArr.join(','))
```

---

So in the case of your example, you are implicitly calling to string in your `for` loop via `m.get(k)` in your `printMap` function before you know if the value is a Map or not. See this line...

```js
console.log(`Current key is ${k} and value is
${map.get(k)}`);
```

An easier way to check this is you just use the browser console. This way you can just `console.log` the `Map` and view it like the screenshot below, see following script.

[image]

```js
const obj = {
  products: {
    lemonade: {
      'product-type': 'beverage',
      'product-details': {
        calories: '129',
        'product-categories': [222, 444],
      },
    },
    limeade: {
      'product-type': 'beverage',
      'product-details': {
        calories: '220',
        'product-categories': [222, 444],
        salesIndex: {
          percentage: 1101,
          demographics: 'region-1',
        },
      },
    },
  },
};

function objectToMap(o) {
  const m = new Map();
  for (const k of Object.keys(o)) {
    const value = o[k];
    // if (value instanceof Object) { // this will include arrays and nulls
    if (typeof value === 'object' && value !== null && !Array.isArray(value)) {
      m.set(k, objectToMap(o[k]));
    } else {
      if (k === 'salesIndex') debugger
      m.set(k, o[k]);
    }
  }
  return m;
}

const m1 = objectToMap(obj.products);

console.log(m1) // view this from browswer console
```

One thing to note is that using `obj instanceof Object` is not ideal as it catches more than you want, namely `Array` and `null` values. So using `typeof value === 'object' && value !== null && !Array.isArray(value)` checks if it's an object then ensures it is neither `null` nor an `Array`. I would look at the difference between `typeof` and `instanceof`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/2449264/6943587. `instanceof` is more for checking for certain `Classes` than generic `Objects`.

Comment: The JSON object cannot simply check for the salesIndex key, as the JSOn can be nested with many different objects. I chose a simple snippet.  From your answer is there no way to get the object without toString()?

Comment: No you should not use `toString` what you have already works, as far as I understand. Your issue is in the `printMap` function that stringifies the output. Are you looking for a `printMap` to work correctly or just for `objectToMap` to work correctly?

Comment: Its the printMap which always prints [object Map ] when i  want to be able to navigate the map entries but it does not work, only shows me [object Map. ].

Comment: Yes! Have you read my answer is full? I explain exactly why your `printMap` function does this, you are calling `console.log` before you check if the value of the map is a map. Checking FIRST this will solve your issue!